# How to apply check on images? How to redirect on the on the tabs i.e <li> from a page

Tags: php, jquery, html, image

Hi my first question is to how to apply checks of dimensions and extensions of image and I also want to know that if my page consists tabs and every tab has different content can I redirect on different tabs from other pages.

Comment: What do you have so far? The fact is many people are likely going to -1 this question because of supreme lack of information.

Comment: I have made a form which accepts an image on submission form will be processed by php the image will be stored in the directory and its path will be stored in mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In javascript, You can get the dimensions of image by

```
var img = document.getElementById('your_image_id');
alert(img.height, img.width);
```

You can check its extensions by `img.src`, but I don't think this is right because browser may check the extension by its content not its src.

Comment: well I am looking to do all the validation in php :|